# How to install wkhtmltopdf on fortrabbit?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, fortrabbit

I am currently in the process of setting up my site on Fortrabbit, I really like the service but have run into my first hurdle. I need to install wkhtmltopdf, a command line tool to convert web pages into html (guide to installation: https://coderwall.com/p/kxno2a?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Abenbradley&t%5B%5D=benbradley).

This should be a very simple process, however, I need to install a few dependencies using sudo apt-get which, as far as I can tell, Fortrabbit does not allow. Is there any way to get around this problem?

I am currently on the free plan although if I can get the site fully functional I will be upgrading to a paid account.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you can upload own files and make them executable, you can upload a pre-compiled binary instead of installing with `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to switch over to DigitalOcean anyway as they are cheaper and you get more control over the server.